# In Flutter, is there a diference if I place my methods inside or outside a widget's build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm starting with Flutter and got some questions about where is the right place to put my methods, inside or outside the widget's build method?

Example:
I have my Widget and create a method showText. Is there a diference if I place this method inside the widget's build method or outside it(as a method of the class itself)?

It seems to work either way.

Thanks

Comment: oh yes. if you put it in the build function, the functions will be reinitialized every time the build method is called, instead if they are outside, they are initialized once. a very small footprint difference. But for a good and readable code base they should be kept outside as class methods,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some reusable piece of code, consider outsourcing it into its own `Widget`.

If that's too much boilerplate, considering helper build-methods is a valid option.
To the Dart compiler, it doesn't really matter where you put these methods, but for less indention and better readability, I recommend putting them inside the class.

Also, consider naming the methods `_build...`. That makes it clear to readers that they are helper build methods. The underscore also ensures that the analyzer warns you if you change the original `build` method and the helper method becomes unused.

Here's an example:

```dart
class A extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _buildTitle(context),
        _buildContent(context),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTitle(BuildContext context) { ... }
  Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) { ... }
}
```